# why is the memory footprint of array larger when row > column

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

```
int **arr_a;//4x268435456
arr_a = new int*[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr_a[i] = new int[268435456];
    for (int j = 0; j < 268435456; j++) {
        arr_a[i][j] = j;
    }
}

int **arr_b;//268435456x4
arr_b = new int*[268435456];
for (int i = 0; i < 268435456; i++) {
    arr_b[i] = new int[4];
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        arr_b[i][j] = j;
    }
}
```

in theory:

```
arr_a:
    sizeof(int**) + 4 * sizeof(int**) + 4 * 268435456 * sizeof(int)
    =4G
arr_b :
    sizeof(int**) + 268435456 * sizeof(int*) + 268435456 * 4 * sizeof(int)
    =6G
```

But in practice:

arr_a = 4G

arr_b = 10.6G ??? WHY....

environment: win10 64bit 32G RAM VS2017

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThXXj.png)

Comment: Your formula for `arr_a` is incorrect.   However, the presence of `268435456` in both calculations should explain why one is bigger than the other.   Difference in calculations versus what is actually allocated can be explained by the library (`malloc()`)  or the system function it calls using bookkeeping overhead and over-allocating (i.e. allocating a multiple of some value, probably measured in K).

Comment: Really, a `std::vector<int>(268435456*4)` is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the results of allocation overhead for small objects. In addition to the four integers in the array itself, `new int[4]` incurs overhead in these two areas:

- **Minimal allocation size** - the chunk of data returned by the allocator has a minimum size, typically at least 32 bytes, of which you use only 16
- **Bookkeeping** - in addition to providing the memory to you, the allocator stores a little chunk of data to help it do the right thing when you call `delete[]`.

These two overheads multiply the amount of memory that you need:

- `268435456 * sizeof(int*)` on 64-bit system is 2G
- Assuming 32-byte min allocation, `268435456 * 32` is another 8G

When you deal with large objects, such as the elements of `arr_a`, the overhead is so tiny in comparison to the allocation size that you can safely ignore it: with only five allocations, we are talking about a few hundred bytes of the 4G total allocation. When objects are small, the additional allocation is comparable to the size of the "payload", and may even exceed it in some extreme cases.

Comment: @SteveTownsend Thank you for the comment! I edited to add info on the relative size of payload and overhead in OP's situation.

Comment: tks, I would upvote twice if I could :-)  This topic touches on something that's not as understood as it should be, which is that reducing heap access in your design is a very good and cheap way to improve performance. Code that uses the heap less runs smaller, and with less contention.  Even the best heap manager is a shared resource.

Answer (score 1):

Every heap allocation carries with it overhead so that the heap manager can track the blocks you have requested.  You need to factor this into your arithmetic as well. It's not as simple as just summing the size of the blocks you requested.

There is a good overview (albeit for Windows 8) [here](http://www.leviathansecurity.com/blog/understanding-the-windows-allocator-a-redux).